# Using an UKF for orientation is there a way to fuse redundant sensor data within the Kalman filter into a single set of state variables?

Tags: matrix, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

I am currently building a UKF for orientation, and would like to fuse redundant sensor data within the Kalman filter into a single set of state variables in order to increase accuracy (ex. Fusing gravitational and magnetic vector data with gyro data). Is there a way to do this within the filter , such as within the H measurement matrix? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly what a Kalman Filter is used for.

First you have to choose the state variables, which could be only the orientation but may also include the change in orientation. In the first case the state transition matrix/function will be identity, in the second case it will not.

The difficult part is setting up the measurement matrix, which tells the UKF how each state variable is related to each measurement variable. (If the state changes, how is the given measurement expected to change.) The UKF will do the rest.